# GAE deploy via Github Actions : Failed to create cloud build: IAM authority does not have the permission 'cloudbuild.builds.create' action CreateBuild

Tags: google-app-engine, github-actions, gcloud, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-iam

*NOTE : For privacy purposes, I changed the project name to "xxx" in this post.*

I am working on a Github Actions workflow to deploy a NuxtJS app to Google App Engine, that fails on this command :

```bash
Running: gcloud app deploy --quiet --format json app.dev.yaml --project xxx --promote
```

It fails with the following error : `Failed to create cloud build: IAM authority does not have the permission 'cloudbuild.builds.create' required for action CreateBuild on resource 'projects/xxx'` followed by an "explanation" that doesn't make much sense (see full log below).

Before that, a `build` job is working fine and creates the `.output` folders with all files as expected and uploads them as artifacts, ready to be downloaded.

Here is the `deploy` job in the Github Actions workflow YAML file that causes the error :

```yaml
  # Build job
  ...

  # App Engine deploy
  deploy:
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    name: App Engine Deploy
    needs: [build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: read
      id-token: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Download build artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: front-build-artifacts

      # STAGING App engine deploy
      - name: Authenticate with Google Cloud on dev environment
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2' # https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_DEV_KEY }}

      - name: App engine deploy on dev environment
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging'
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v2 # https://github.com/marketplace/actions/deploy-to-app-engine
        with:
          project_id: xxx
          deliverables: 'app.dev.yaml'
```

```bash
Run google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v2
  with:
    project_id: xxx
    deliverables: app.dev.yaml
    promote: true
  env:
    CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE: /home/runner/work/XXX-front/XXX-front/gha-creds-6ada118c927f2f3a.json
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /home/runner/work/XXX-front/XXX-front/gha-creds-6ada118c927f2f3a.json
    GOOGLE_GHA_CREDS_PATH: /home/runner/work/XXX-front/XXX-front/gha-creds-6ada118c927f2f3a.json
    CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT: xxx
    CLOUDSDK_PROJECT: xxx
    GCLOUD_PROJECT: xxx
    GCP_PROJECT: xxx
    GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT: xxx
/usr/bin/tar xz --warning=no-unknown-keyword --overwrite -C /home/runner/work/_temp/11678d2d-0405-4945-b890-f883e482c60e -f /home/runner/work/_temp/8b9fb6d2-eb23-4081-96f2-f65cd470c180
Successfully authenticated
Running: gcloud app deploy --quiet --format json app.dev.yaml --project xxx --promote
Error: google-github-actions/deploy-appengine failed with: failed to execute gcloud command `gcloud app deploy --quiet --format json app.dev.yaml --project xxx --promote`: Services to deploy:

descriptor:                  [/home/runner/work/XXX-front/XXX-front/app.dev.yaml]
source:                      [/home/runner/work/XXX-front/XXX-front]
target project:              [xxx]
target service:              [default]
target version:              [20240208t163840]
target url:                  [https://xxx.ew.r.appspot.com]
target service account:      [xxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com]


Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 623 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...
..................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] Failed to create cloud build: IAM authority does not have the permission 'cloudbuild.builds.create' required for action CreateBuild on resource 'projects/xxx'. Explanation:  Security Context: RecordingSecurityContext{delegate=ValidatedSecurityContextWithSystemAuthorizationPolicy{delegate=ValidatedSecurityContextWithRegistryHandle{delegate=ValidatedSecurityContextWithObligations{delegate=ContextWithGaiaMintToken{delegate=ValidatedIamSecurityContext{user=gaiauser/0xXXXXXXXX, creds=EndUserCreds{loggable_credential { type: GAIA_MINT loggable_gaia_mint { } } loggable_credential { type: SERVICE_CONTROL_TOKEN }}, peer=protocol=loas;psp_version=0;level=strong_privacy_and_integrity;host=whfw5.prod.google.com;is_authenticated_host=false;role=cloud-build-api;user=app-engine-zeus-worker;is_delegated=true;jobname_chosen_by_user=prod-europe-west1.cloud-build-api, InternalIAMIdentity{log=data_access_reason { manual_reason: "Acquiring DAT for long-lived Admin API procedures." } originator { scope: GAIA_USER gaia_user { user_id: XXXXXXXXXX } }}}}}}}}
com.google.apps.framework.auth.IamPermissionDeniedException: IAM authority does not have the permission 'cloudbuild.builds.create' required for action CreateBuild on resource 'projects/xxx'. Explanation:  Security Context: RecordingSecurityContext{delegate=ValidatedSecurityContextWithSystemAuthorizationPolicy{delegate=ValidatedSecurityContextWithRegistryHandle{delegate=ValidatedSecurityContextWithObligations{delegate=ContextWithGaiaMintToken{delegate=ValidatedIamSecurityContext{user=gaiauser/0xXXXXXXXX, creds=EndUserCreds{loggable_credential { type: GAIA_MINT loggable_gaia_mint { } } loggable_credential { type: SERVICE_CONTROL_TOKEN }}, peer=protocol=loas;psp_version=0;level=strong_privacy_and_integrity;host=whfw5.prod.google.com;is_authenticated_host=false;role=cloud-build-api;user=app-engine-zeus-worker;is_delegated=true;jobname_chosen_by_user=prod-europe-west1.cloud-build-api, InternalIAMIdentity{log=data_access_reason { manual_reason: "Acquiring DAT for long-lived Admin API procedures." } originator { scope: GAIA_USER gaia_user { user_id: XXXXXXXXXX} }}}}}}}}.
```

The Google Cloud authentication using the env `credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_DEV_KEY }}` works fine, it does authenticate as a Service Account that has the following roles :

- App Engine Standard Environment Service Agent
- Cloud Build Service Agent
- Cloud Functions Service Agent
- Editor
- Firebase Extensions API Service Agent
- Firebase Service Management Service Agent
- Owner
- Service Account Token Creator
- Service Account User

It seems to me that it's a permission issue with that service account, but I don't understand which roles could be missing.

Additionally, if anyone can explain better what the "Explanation:  Security Context" part of the logs mean, I'd be glad to know !

Comment: Have you check this documentation about [Troubleshooting:   Build trigger fails due to missing cloudbuild.builds.create permission](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/troubleshoot%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bing#build_trigger_f%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bails_due_to_missing_%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcloudbuildbuildscrea%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bte_permission)?